# Concatenate queries in SQL using PHP

Tags: php

I cannot spot the difference of these queries.

```
$lastact="SELECT * FROM DOC_DETAILS WHERE 1=1 AND DOC_TYPE=$emp_id";    
$whr="";
```

1.
...

```
$docfk=$emprow['ICID'];
$whr .= " AND DOC_TYPE=$docfk";
$qry1=mysqli_query($conn,$lastact .$whr);
```

...

2.
...

```
$qry1=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM DOC_DETAILS WHERE 1=1 AND DOC_FK=$docfk");
```

...

the 1st query doesn't return any result while the 2nd works fine.

Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL in the first query will be

```
SELECT * FROM DOC_DETAILS WHERE 1=1 AND DOC_TYPE=$emp_id AND DOC_TYPE=$docfk
```

If emp_id and docfk are different this will return no results.

Answer (score 0):

In the first query you add **"DOC_TYPE=$emp_id"** but in second query **"DOC_TYPE=$emp_id"** this condition not found so first need to check this condition add/remove if not getting result then tell me again

Comment: aren't both queries should return same data?I can't understand why the condition DOC_FK=$docfk is returning false.The second query is working well.The first query where i used concatenation is not. Thanks much.